# Assign string used as a link to a filename when batch dowloading through url's with R

Tags: r

I am downloading xls files from  [this page](https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/2906) with a loop through url's with R :

```
for(i in 8:56) {
   i1 <- sprintf('%02d', i)
   url <- paste0("https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/29", i1, "?file=1")
   file <- paste0("myExcel_", i, ".xls")
   if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file) 
}
```

I want to assign the string used as a link to each filename downloaded

For example I want to use "ds219.xls" as file name for https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/2908

`<a href="2908?file=1">ds219.xls</a>`

Comment: the `assign` function might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name you need is in the URL header. So try the following function:

```
getURLFilename <- function(url){
  require(stringi)
  hdr <-paste(curlGetHeaders(url),collapse = '')
  fname <- as.vector(stri_match(hdr,regex = '(?<=filename=\\").*(?=\\")'))
  fname
}
```

For the URL you've given:

```
getURLFilename('https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/2908?file=1')
# [1] "ds219.xls"
```

Then, in your loop use:

```
file <- getURLFilename(url)
if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file)
```