# Downloading xls files with a loop through url's gives me corrupted files

Tags: r

I am downloading xls files from  [this page](https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/2906) with a loop through url's with R ([based on this first step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625988/assign-string-used-as-a-link-to-a-filename-when-batch-dowloading-through-urls-w/56626542#56626542)):

```
getURLFilename <- function(url){
  require(stringi)
  hdr <-paste(curlGetHeaders(url),collapse = '')
  fname <- as.vector(stri_match(hdr,regex = '(?<=filename=\\").*(?=\\")'))
  fname
}


for(i in 8:56) {
  i1 <- sprintf('%02d', i)
  url <- paste0("https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/29", i1, "?file=1")
  file <- paste0("myExcel_", i, ".xls")
  if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file) 
 }
```

The files are downloaded but corrupted.

Comment: Not every file in those list of urls are xls files some are pdf's as well and I am guessing those are the ones which are corrupted?

Comment: All the files are corrupted both pdf and xls files

Comment: You're saving the pdfs as xls. Plus, I just answered this question for you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625988/assign-string-used-as-a-link-to-a-filename-when-batch-dowloading-through-urls-w/56626542#56626542. If you use the right file name, it should work as expected. Please don't make multiple posts for the same problem.

Comment: @Rohit tank you for helping. I asked a new question because, for me,  naming and corrupted files are differentes questions. pdf are "blanks" and xls are corrupted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mode="wb"` in `download.file` to write the file in binary mode.

```
library(readxl)
for (i in 8:55) {
  i1 <- sprintf('%02d', i)
  url <- paste0("https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/29", i1, "?file=1")
  if (is.na(format_from_signature(url))) {
    file <- paste0("myPdf_", i, ".pdf")
  } else {
    file <- paste0("myExcel_", i, ".xls")
  }
  if (!file.exists(file)) download.file(url, file, mode="wb") 
}
```

Now the downloaded Excel files are not corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit different approach using `rvest` to scrape the URL's to download and filename to save only the XLS files and not the PDF's.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/2906"

#Scrape the nodes which we are interested in 
target_nodes <- url %>%
                  read_html() %>%
                  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="annexes"]') %>%
                  html_nodes("a")

#Get the indices which ends with xls
inds <- target_nodes %>% html_text() %>% grep("xls$", .)

#Get the corresponding URL for the xls files and paste it with prefix
target_urls <- target_nodes %>% 
                    html_attr("href") %>% .[inds] %>% 
                    paste0("https://journals.openedition.org/acrh/", .)

#Get the target name to save file
target_name <- target_nodes %>% 
                    html_text() %>% 
                    grep("xls$", ., value = TRUE) %>% 
                    sub("\\s+", ".", .) %>% 
                    paste0("/folder_path/to/storefiles/", .)

#Download the files and store them at target_name location
mapply(download.file, target_urls, target_name)
```

I manually verified 3-4 files on my system and I am able to open them and the data match as well when I manually download them from the `url`.

Comment: Thank you for helping but I have the same issue when opening files with Excel 2007. Files are damaged and Excelcould not recover all the data

Comment: @Wilcar strange. I am not sure what could be the problem since it works perfectly fine for me when using office 365. Not sure, if it matters.

Comment: I always get the same problem my files are corrupted (using any version of Excel)

Comment: @Wilcar Are you not able to open the files? It doesn't even work for 1 file? I just tried this again now and it works absolutely fine for me. I can open the files without any problem in excel.